# How to decide the coordinates i.e x and y axis in placing the android component?

Tags: android

I am new to android and looking for the clearity . I am trying to understand how does the components are placed inside the layout . For eg : if I have a relative layout and I am trying to place a textview inside it and I need to place it with the margin-top of 10px or 10dp if it will show at different positions in different devices (because of the phones of different screen sizes) if so how it can be generic so that margin-top will remain same on all the devices ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You gotta go with dp for safeness sake. ixel population may vary across devices. So using pixels is surely not safe. But dp(density-independent pixels) is not specific. It takes advantage of the pixel density and adjusts itself across various devices.

> One dp is a virtual pixel unit that's roughly equal to one pixel on a medium-density screen (160dpi; the "baseline" density). Android translates this value to the appropriate number of real pixels for each other density.

[Official explanation here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities)

Comment: Thank You , but I tried this and it giving different views in different sized screen ?? How to make UI which is compatible for all the screens ?

Comment: To achieve compatibility, you can use constraint layout. Even then, it won't be enough. So, one thing you can do to solve vertical UI problems are by covering all the components with a scrollView, inorder to prevent the components from being cut off. And for horizontal problems, you can do the sizing dynamically. To do that, find the screen size dynamically and change the spacing accordingly. It sure may not be the best way, but there is no, so called 'straight forward way'.